# Optimizing code by eliminating 'for' loops

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, lapply, sapply

I have this code I'm working with and it has so many for loops. Here is a part of the code which is most confusing to optimize due to the dimensions.

```
calcobj_i <- function (X, iter, pa) 
{ 
    ww = rep(0, pa$n)
    for (k in 1:pa$K) {
        w = iter$cw[k] * 
                dmnorm(X, iter$center[k,], iter$Lambda[,,k] %*% 
                t(iter$Lambda[,,k]) + iter$Psi[,,k]) 
        w = w*(w>=0) 
        ww = w+ww 
    }
}
```

Here `iter` and `pa` are lists containing vectors and matrices like `lambda`, `cw`, `center`, and `Psi` with dimensions specified above and `X` is a matrix. `dmnorm` is the multivariate normal density function which gives a vector of values.

I want to know how to use `apply`, `lapply` or any other transformation on these type of functions.